# Scrapy Selector attribute

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I use the following website to test:

`scrapy shell http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/user/login#`

And do some test:

**Input 1:**

`response.xpath('//div//[@style]/input')`

**Output 1:**

```
[<Selector xpath='//div[@style]/input' data='<input name="_next" type="hidden" value='>,  

<Selector xpath='//div[@style]/input' data='<input name="_formkey" type="hidden" val'>,  

<Selector xpath='//div[@style]/input' data='<input name="_formname" type="hidden" va'>]
```

**Input 2:**

`response.xpath('//div//@style/input')`

**Output 2:**

`[]`

**Input 3:**

`response.xpath('//div//@style/input') == response.xpath('//div[style]/input')`

**Output 3:**

`True`

I want to know how different 1 and 2 is,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're looking for this selector:

```
response.xpath('//div[@style]/input')
```

This is how it works:

1. select all the `div` elements from the document (`//div`);
2. for each one of those, select only the ones which have a `style` attribute (`[@style]`);
3. select the `input` nodes which are descendants of the elements selected on step 2 (`/input`).

Your 2nd selector (`//div//@style/input`) wouldn't work well because it does:

1. select all the `div` elements from the page (`//div`);
2. select the `style` attribute from every descendant of the divs selected in step 1 (`//@style`);
3. select the `input` nodes which are **direct descendants** of the `style` attributes, which is something that doesn't exist (`/input`).